# Confluent .net (rdkafka) commit on consumer dispose

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

The confluent advanced consumer [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/AdvancedConsumer/Program.cs) has the following code (trimmed for brevity).

```
        using (var consumer = new Consumer<Null, string>(constructConfig(brokerList, false), null, new StringDeserializer(Encoding.UTF8)))
        {
            while (!cancelled)
            {
                Message<Null, string> msg;
                if (!consumer.Consume(out msg, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)))
                {
                    continue;
                }                    

                if (msg.Offset % 5 == 0)
                {                        
                    consumer.CommitAsync(msg).Result;                        
                }
            }
        }
```

Auto-commit is false.
My question is what happens if the 'cancelled' trigger is flagged while there are still outstanding commits. Are the messages left uncommitted and therefore will be received again? I was am hoping that the consumer would commit on disposing, but I can't see anything like that in the implementation. I can do some tests to see what happens, but I was hoping for an 'official' answer in case my tests do not cover all cases.

Comment: Irrelevant to the actual question but: is it even a correct implementation? Without memory fences what does guarantee that `cancelled = true;` is ever observed by the other thread?

Comment: Lets just say `cancelled` is volatile

Answer (score 1):

First note, you should use `CommitAsync` only when `enable.auto.commit` is set to `false` (this is the case in the Advanced Consumer example - this need some more comments and wiki input). If you are using auto-commit (by default), you will automatically commit when disposing (this is on librdkafka side when calling rd_kafka_destroy)

Here, we are waiting for `CommitAsync` to complete (via `.Result`) and it's called on the same thread than the while loop, so there won't be "in flight" commits reuests.

If you use manual commit (this is the case in the complete code snippet), you will have to commit manually before disposing- this indeed is missing from example, will add it. As stated, in manual commit, you have to commit yourself (there are cases where user won't want to commit when disposing)

I also just spotted a bug, if you call CommitAsync but don't wait for it before disposing, you may have a thread stuck or an accessViolationException, will look to correct this (https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/279) So you should always await for CommitAsync to complete before dispoing for the time being

Comment: +1 for the hint about commitAsync when disposing. But my question remains - will the outstanding commits be done on disposing? From my testing so far, I think that the answer is no.

Comment: When enable.auto.commit is True, consumer does commit on dispose, but in my case, it stays stuck. Eventually  (after 70 min) it times out with : Confluent.Kafka.KafkaException: Local: Timed out
   at Confluent.Kafka.Impl.SafeKafkaHandle.ConsumerClose()

Comment: If you use auto commit, it will. If you specify manual commit, you will have to call and wait for CommitAsync to complete before disposing. If you don't await it, the behaviour is not predictable (may commit, may not, and may throw exception). If it's not clear, please detail what you mean by "outstanding commits
@SasaNinkovic I'm interested in knowing more, can you detail here your config or post on issue on github? Thanks!